# Restart Fibre channel controller after blade bootup IBM HS bladecentre

Tags: storage-area-network, ibm, fibre-channel, bladecenter

I have a remote system that needs to resume on startup.  If the system is simply powered on then the blades boot before the SAN is online and then the only thing you can do is restart the systems.

Is it possible to restart the fibre channel controller?  That way I could have a system restart the controller after boot, connect to the SAN and then restart all servers requiring SAN information?

Please note that I'm not a sys admin, just shooting for ideas to get a clean startup to work, apologies if my terminology is wrong.

Comment: I'm unable to deduce if you are booting from the SAN or from local disks. If you boot from local, you could add delays to the bootloader so the SAN is up first. Or test if the LUNs are available and if not: reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a HP blade guy myself but they have individual blade boot delay options, perhaps the IBM ones have the same function?

Comment: I asked exactly that question and no one seemed to think so....

Comment: @Spence: I can't imagine the blades not having such an option. Keep digging, if an answer doesn't surface you could try calling IBM (very helpful support in my experience)

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'restart the FC controller', yes you can do so. Have the controller issue a LIP and rescan for LUNs on the FC fabric. How to do so depends on the OS.

I also wrote some other suggestions in your [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/125228/ibm-bladecentre-h-bootup-sequence-control):

You can't directly control the powerup sequence of the blades in a BladeCenter, but you can control the amount of time each takes to boot.
...
Another option would be to control blade powerup via some kind of external script. Have an external system that upon startup, starts the blades in the appropriate order via telnet/SNMP/whatever.